# Can you get into Oola's old lab?

Tags: guild-wars-2

So in Metrica Province there is the old ruins of Oola's lab, and from the mini-map it looks like you can go through it and pop out the other side.

[image]

Has anyone managed to get inside? Or is it permanently locked?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, in fact you can! (There's often a rich copper vein waiting by the exit for you)

However, to open the door to the lab, you need an [Energy Crystal](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Energy_Crystal), which is a random drop from mobs in the zone.

Once you have one, you can take the crystal to the door, hand it to researcher Orl, and you will start an event that takes you through Oola's lab.

Comment: There are also "Energy Crystals" that are not rare now. It seems like they did not work.